# PeriodicSync is not working in android kitkat and lollipop

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am performing sync in my application for every 12 hours ,earlier i tried in android 4.4 below versions sync adapter is working fine, but kitkat and above periodicsync is not even triggering please help me.

```
public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
    Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
    String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                setSyncAdapter(account, authority).build();
        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
    } else {
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I would appreciate any tip

Comment: I think I found the problem. I had the auto-sync data option turned off. Go Settings->Accounts->[overflow menu]->Auto-sync data

Comment: And be sure you set 'android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"' in your syncadapter.xml and 'android:syncable="true"' in your provider element of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Starting Android 7 the minimum frequency is 15 min.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945718/contentresolver-addperiodicsync-interval-round-up/47409131#47409131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this question,for kitkat and above we need to write separate code

code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            SyncRequest.Builder b = (new SyncRequest.Builder()).syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime);
            b.setSyncAdapter(account, authority);
            b.setExtras(new Bundle());
            ContentResolver.requestSync(b.build());
        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(),
                    syncInterval);
```