# what is the minimum pollfrequency for ContentResolver.addperiodicSync()?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

According [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addPeriodicSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long)) docs it minimum of 60 mins is enforced but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949976/6485361) answer it was 60 secs. What is the correct min pollFrequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, After experimenting on my app I was able sync every minute, so there is a mistake with the andriod documentation. Only 60 secs minimum value is enforced not 60 minutes.