# Periodic sync runs every time

Tags: android, synchronization

I am trying to build a periodic sync in my android app to run periodically every 1 hour. I am following an example from android developer website:

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(createDummyAccount(this, "account name"),
                MyContentProvider.AUTHORITY,
                Bundle.EMPTY, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.periodic_sync_interval));
```

The problem is that sync is being triggered every time the activity is being launched even within one minute.

Can you help please?

Comment: It's behaviour can variate between versions of android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945718/contentresolver-addperiodicsync-interval-round-up
Also documantation implies that "This means that the actual start time may drift."

Answer (score 0):

Please check the interval documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addPeriodicSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long)

```
pollFrequency   long: how frequently the sync should be performed, in seconds. On Android API level 24 and above, a minmam interval of 15 minutes is enforced. On previous versions, the minimum interval is 1 hour.
```

Comment: my problem is that sync is being triggered too much even if I set the period to 3600 sec